# Encode integer pandas dataframe column to padded 16 bit binary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binary

I would like to encode integers stored in a pandas dataframe column into respective 16-bit binary numbers which correspond to bit positions in those integers. I would also need to pad leading zeros for numbers with corresponding binary less than 16 bits. For example, given one column containing integers ranging from 0 to 33000, for an integer value of 20 (10100 in binary) I would like to produce 16 columns with values 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 and so on across the entire column.

Answer (score 2):

### Setup

Consider the data frame `df` with column `'A'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(16)))
```

### Numpy broadcasting and bit shifting

```
a = df.A.values
n = int(np.log2(a.max() + 1))
b = (a[:, None] >> np.arange(n)[::-1]) & 1

pd.DataFrame(b)

    0  1  2  3
0   0  0  0  0
1   0  0  0  1
2   0  0  1  0
3   0  0  1  1
4   0  1  0  0
5   0  1  0  1
6   0  1  1  0
7   0  1  1  1
8   1  0  0  0
9   1  0  0  1
10  1  0  1  0
11  1  0  1  1
12  1  1  0  0
13  1  1  0  1
14  1  1  1  0
15  1  1  1  1
```

---

### String formatting with f-strings

```
n = int(np.log2(df.A.max() + 1))

pd.DataFrame([list(map(int, f'{i:0{n}b}')) for i in df.A])

    0  1  2  3
0   0  0  0  0
1   0  0  0  1
2   0  0  1  0
3   0  0  1  1
4   0  1  0  0
5   0  1  0  1
6   0  1  1  0
7   0  1  1  1
8   1  0  0  0
9   1  0  0  1
10  1  0  1  0
11  1  0  1  1
12  1  1  0  0
13  1  1  0  1
14  1  1  1  0
15  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```
x = 20
bin_string = format(x, '016b')
df = pd.DataFrame(list(bin_string)).T
```

I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to know if that's sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! that sounds kind of like what I'm trying to do, except I'm starting with a data frame column. My current solution looks like this:      
    
    `df_integer_column = data_frame[col_index]`        
    
    `data_frame_new = pandas.DataFrame([list(f'{i:16b}') for i in   
     df_integer_column], index=data_frame.index,   
     columns=column_names_list)`

However this doesn't pad the binary output, e.g. for 20 I get just 5 columns with 1, 0, 1, 0, 0

Comment: Could you explain how to implement your solution assuming x was a data frame column containing integers? Thanks!